# I want to use Ubuntu, but I have some issues with hardware peripherals

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, hardware, headset

I'm really interested in Ubuntu, but I've always run into a constant blockade that prevents me from moving forward; lack of driver support for the devices I use. Below is my current mouse and headset, and the keyboard and new mouse I plan on eventually getting.

Currently, I have a Logitech G35 headset and a Logitech M510 mouse. I also plan on getting a Corsair K95 keyboard, and a SteelSeries Sensei mouse.

My main problem at the moment is that Logitech doesn't support Linux. The mouse works fine without SetPoint, it's configuration software, but offers advanced features. A replacement program for it or a way to get SetPoint working on Linux would be appreciated, but not required. As for the G35 headset, it makes use of the Logitech Gaming Software, which provides surround sound and extra features. I honestly don't need the extra feature, but it's appreciated. However, once I buy the keyboard and new mouse, replacement programs or versions that work on Linux are necessary due to the features.

So, to sum it up, my main problem is lack of driver support for my current devices, and in want to know if there's software I can use to fix my predicament that I might have missed when I looked. Alternatively, how many of these can I successfully run on WINE and get the expected function?

[I already asked this question on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/21nouc/i_need_some_help_with_my_peripherals/), and got one answer and a prompt to ask here, so I'm asking just in case they missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider your approach on using Ubuntu as your main OS. Ubuntu is an Open Source OS based on Debian. This makes it depend on voluntary free contributions from developers all around the world.

> It is **us** not them who build the OS.

Drivers are often provided for free from the manufacturers of hardware but sadly not all manufacturers contribute with Open Source software to support their devices. Then they may have a closed source proprietary driver or additional software available, but some manufacturers decide to **not support Ubuntu**. It is my strong believe that we then should in return not support these manufacturers by simply not buying their products.

> If you are not happy with this approach then Ubuntu/Linux is not the right place for you. You should pay for a closed source OS where you can expect that all of your drivers and software should work without issues.

As a rule of thumb brand-new hardware will always take some time until we can provide drivers to make them work. Do not expect the community to be able to support hardware at the time of release. This is even more so after the manufacturer made a great secret on  specifications, hence making the development of drivers and tools almost impossible.

After a while however most devices will be supported. You may then also find, that older devices will have a much longer support span than offered from a proprietary OS. Many people needed to switch from XP to Ubuntu just because later Windows versions did no longer support their hardwares.

To be able to use Ubuntu without frustration we should therefore search communtiy places for issues and solutions **before** we buy hardware. We will see that most hardware is supported **out of the box**, i.e. no drivers are needed to have it working, just plug them in. This too is different to another OS. Other hardware may need some tweaks to work:

- [Logitech k350 keyboard and m510 mouse not working unless I unplug and replug dongle 20 times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326087/logitech-k350-keyboard-and-m510-mouse-not-working-unless-i-unplug-and-replug-don)
- [Logitech USB headset not working on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131812/logitech-usb-headset-not-working-on-12-04)

Please also note that while having support for a device this does not always mean that all fancy special secret features will work the same as they do on Windows. But then this entirely is the responsibility of the manufacturers.

> **Stay with Windows if you need any such device or feature fully supported.**

For example I still have a copy of Windows running in a virtual machine because the Canon printer I had left over from when I was still running on Windows will not let me print on photo paper or CDs in a way only remotely as comfortable as it does from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For keybindings, you can download xbindkeys (similar process to the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse)).  As far as the headset, I have a G930 and i use Debian Linux.  It registers as two devices, one as a stereo headset and the other as a 5.1 surround sound.  Both modes work perfectly in Linux.  It is true that Logitech provides no driver support on Linux, but as I type this post on my G710+ keyboard, listening to Pithos on my Logitech G930 headset, and clicking "Post Your Answer" on my G600 mouse, I couldn't be happier with the way my components work in Linux.